# Printing AND writing the RIGHTLY formatted number

Tags: python, pandas, formatting

While being able to print # of decimals in console, I am significantly more challenged when attempting to write to a csv with the RIGHTLY formatted number. In the code below I somehow managed to divide integers in '000s, and have the result thrown into a csv, but I cannot get rid of the extra ".,". The for loop is really a hard challenge. Maybe, someone could tell me how to crack the puzzle.

View code strings below. Should have looked like, both in print in console AND in the csv file I am writing to:

23,400,344.567, 54,363,744.678, 56,789,117.456, 4,132,454.987

INPUT:

```
import pandas as pd

def insert_comma(s):
     str=''
     count=0
     for n in reversed(s):
          str += n
          count+=1
          if count == 3:
               str += ','
               count=0

     return ''.join([i for i in reversed(str)][1:])


d = {'Quarters' : ['Quarter1','Quarter2','Quarter3','Quarter4'],
 'Revenue':[23400344.567, 54363744.678, 56789117.456, 4132454.987]}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)

df['Revenue']=df.apply(lambda x: insert_comma(str(x['Revenue'] / 1000)), axis=1)

# pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.0f}'.format

df.to_csv("C:\\Users\\jcst\\Desktop\\Private\\Python data\\new8.csv", sep=";")

# round to two decimal places in python pandas

# .options.display.float_format = '{:.0f}'.format
print(df)
```

OUTPUT

```
   Quarters      Revenue
0  Quarter1  234,00.,344
1  Quarter2  543,63.,744
2  Quarter3  567,89.,117
3  Quarter4    1,32.,454
```

Comment: What's your expected output? If it's `"23,400,344.567"`, you'll never get that because you're dividing by 1000 in the lambda. Also, you don't seem to be accounting for the decimal within the `insert_comma` function.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this.  Use format string to use comma(s) and 3 decimal places for all rows in Revenue column.

```
df['Revenue']=df['Revenue'].apply('{0:,.3f}'.format)
```

Result:

```
   Quarters         Revenue
0  Quarter1  23,400,344.567
1  Quarter2  54,363,744.678
2  Quarter3  56,789,117.456
3  Quarter4   4,132,454.987
```

Comment: Excellent, it worked….and @DZ, you're so right...the "/ 1000" was added by mistake and originated from a desperate attempt to control formatting that way…;o)))

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

```
insertCommas = lambda x: format(x, ',')
```

Works like this:

```
>>> insertCommas(23400344.567)
'23,400,344.567'
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
df['Revenue'] = df['Revenue'].apply(lambda x:f"{x:,.3f}")
```

This solution uses [Python 3.6+ f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) to insert commas as thousand separator and show 3 decimals.